# VS2008 - Replace var with inferred type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

My team just received the code written by a contractor, and the contractor had a preference for using type inference with `var`. Our team prefers explicit typing by using the actual type (as in below):

```
Type someName = new Type();
IList<TypeTwo> someOther = someClass.getStuff();
```

Whereas the contractor delivered

```
var someOther = someClass.getStuff();
```

Visual Studio 2008 knows what the inferred type is, as I can see by hovering the var keyword

My question is, is there a way to do a global find and replace var to the inferred type?

Comment: I have often wondered this myself if there is such and addin :)

Comment: Removed editorializing about `var` in order to sidestep any religious argument on the topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool to refactor C# var to explicit type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289743/tool-to-refactor-c-sharp-var-to-explicit-type)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think VS 2008 (or 2010 for that matter) has this functionality, but [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) has the "Replace 'var' with explicit type declaration" [context-action](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Options__Languages__CSharp__Context_Actions.html) that you can use on a case-by-case basis to type locals explicitly. If you want to go the whole hog, there's a "Code Cleanup" operation that can be used to perform this refactoring for an entire block/file/project/solution.

Do note that this plugin is not free.

Comment: Thanks, Ani. Since this is a cheap ($349), I'll go check if my company can buy this. Or I'll buy a single license myself. Again, thanks very much!