# Implicitly-Typed Out Parameters

Tags: c#, generics, out, implicit-typing

In a similar vein to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073134/implicitly-typed-variables-in-try-catch), I decided to see if it was possible to pull `out` parameters from a method into implicitly-typed variables without having to define the types.  My ideal solution would look something like this:

```
var result = LiftOutParam((out p1, out p2, out p3) => {
    return CallMyMethod(i1, i2, out p1, out p2, out p3);
});
var o1 = result.Item1;
var o2 = result.Item2;
var o3 = result.Item3;
var returnValue = result.Item4;
```

In this case, `CallMyMethod` has 2 normal input variables, 3 `out` parameters, and a return value.  I want the compiler to automatically determine the types of `o1`, `o2`, `o3`, and `returnValue` based on the semantics of the delegate passed into `LiftOutParam`.  So I created some helper delegates and methods, for each combination of out parameters.  Here's an example for 3 `out` parameters:

```
public delegate TReturn Lift<T1, T2, T3, TReturn>(
    out T1 o1, out T2 o2, out T3 o3);

public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, TReturn> LiftOutParam<T1, T2, T3, TReturn>(
    Lift<T1, T2, T3, TReturn> Lift) {

    T1 o1;
    T2 o2;
    T3 o3;
    TReturn ret = Lift(out o1, out o2, out o3);
    return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, TReturn>(o1, o2, o3, ret);
}
```

In theory, the compiler should be able to determine the types `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, and `TReturn` based on the semantics of the delegate `(out p1, out p2, out p3) => { return CallMyMethod(i1, i2, out p1, out p2, out p3); }`.  However, the above code doesn't compile unless I specify the types of each of the `out` parameters in the delegate.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?  To write a generic helper method that can pull the values of `out` parameters into implicitly-typed local variables without having to explicitly define the types anywhere?

Comment: `(out p1, out p2, out p3)` isn't a valid lambda signature.  At least, not in LINQPad.  Without specifying `out`, I get that I need to use the `out` keyword, but when I do specify it, it doesn't recognize the syntax.  This makes sense, because where would that `out` parameter go?

Comment: @Bobson: Agreed, I was having the same problem.

Comment: AFAIK that is a restriction on the syntax of lambda expressions and anonymous delegates. If you use `out` or `ref`, then the argument type must be specified.

Comment: @mikez: Interesting.  Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @mikez If you use an old-style anonymous method, and this is a `ref` parameter (not `out` parameter) that you're not going to use, you can leave out all parameters and the parenthesis as usual. Like so: `DelegateTypeWithRefParameter f = delegate { Console.WriteLine("Cool"); };`

Comment: @mellamokb The controlling section of the C# spec for lambda expressions is 7.15 which clearly specifies that if `ref` or `out` is used then type must be specified for it to be valid.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I think that is consistent with what I said, but to clarify if you *use* the `out` or `ref` keywords in the anonymous function signature (either delegate or lambda style) then the type must be specified. Your delegate does not use the `ref` or `out` keyword. The same section I mentioned above (7.15) applies to the delegate style syntax.

Comment: @mikez What I said wasn't meant to "correct" you. I agree the C# Specification states all this. Of course, it would be strange if `ref` or `out` (or `params`) was alone in front of the parameter name; that's the type's position. But there **are** diferences, of course. In a lambda, the parameters must always be there, but the type can be omitted in some cases. In an anonymous method, the parameters can be omitted, but if the parameters are there, they must be with their types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. When a `ref` or `out` modifier is needed for one or more of the parameters of a lambda expression, syntax requires that you **must** specify the type for all of the parameters of the lambda expression. This is a syntax thing and applies no matter if the compiler would have been able to infer the types or not.
2. There must be a type to infer. If you have a method

   ```
   void MyMethod<T>(Action<T> action)
   {
   }
   ```

   then you can't call this method like this: `MyMethod(t => { });` Because in this case there's no way to infer what `T` is. `T` **must** be infered to be one specific type. This could be a type that depends on another generic parameter that is in scope when the `MyMethod` is called.

Answer (score 2):

C# compiler cannot infer generic types from delegates with method passed in. More here [C# 3.0 generic type inference - passing a delegate as a function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407983/c-sharp-3-0-generic-type-inference-passing-a-delegate-as-a-function-parameter) . It doesn't matter if it is normal parameter or ref/out parameter.

Possibly related:
C# cannot infer return types of passed delegates/lambdas as explained in [Generic methods in .NET cannot have their return types inferred. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203643/generic-methods-in-net-cannot-have-their-return-types-inferred-why) .

Comment: I know from the example I linked that it is possible for the compiler to infer the return type.  However, I think it's the parameters that are the problem - which didn't apply to my linked example. I think it makes sense now.