# Replace var with explicit type not working in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Following article mentions var can be replaced with explicit type.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/convert-var-to-explicit-type?view=vs-2017

It used to work one time, but now it doesn't now. What could be the setting?

Comment: Hi. Not working as when you click it it does nothing or that it does not give the option to do it anymore?

Comment: @markorial it does not give option to do it anymore. I have even checked my settings according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46372419/2817086. It still doesnt work

Comment: have you tried deleting the visual studio user settings folder to restore settings to absolute defaults?

Comment: it doesnt work for me even in visual studio 2019

Comment: is it on the same project because the only idea i have left atm is that the particular suggestion was suppressed  maybe. Other than that i checked my vs2017 settings and i have it on "Refactoring only" and it works for me every time.